# How can I validate inputs directly from the database without page reloading?

Tags: php, jquery, post

I'm just a PHP starter and now I want to learn JQUERY, on my learning process I practice on validating inputs usually I validate my inputs using a pure PHP code only and every time I validate the inputs the page reloads and now I want to improve in doing things I found some articles like http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/, http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/ (can't post other links) but I am more confused because they have different approach and I want to use the approach from the JQUERY tutorial but I haven't found any good tutorials and there is no tutorials on JQUERY's site that is using a database, usually I code like this:

```
<form method="post">
<label for="Username">Username:</label>
<input id="Username" type="text" name="username">
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['msg'])){
$msg=$_SESSION['msg'];
echo '<label for="Username">'.$msg.'</label>';
?>
<input type="submit" name="reg">
</form>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['reg'])){
$result=//check username from database here
if($result){
$_SESSION['msg']='username not available.';
}
else {
$_SESSION['msg']='username available.';
}
}
?>
```

Now I want to learn how can I validate inputs directly from the database without reloading the page? I don't know where should I start, what to add in my code. Any help, advice or suggestions will be really a big help for me :)

Comment: directly from the database means backend ?
i think in that case you can do that by ajax.

Comment: Write your validation script as though you're expecting a page refresh. Instead of outputting error messages, put them in a JSON array and print the JSON data. Then call the script from the AJAX function. It's really that simple.

Comment: yes sir, I read the tutorials in jquery but doesn't have a database.

Comment: Couldn't have said that better myself @Matt, seems I've been +1ing you all over SO today!

Comment: @Aby As Matt said, just treat the PHP side of things as you would normally when connecting to a database. Instead of echoing the messages you echo a JSON response.

Comment: @BrainedWashed : Thats where i was going, i got confused by "Database validation".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first, in your form add a onSubmit function

```
 <form name='myform' type='POST' action='http://www.action.fr' onSubmit="return check_form()">
```

you can do this in ajax like that

```
function check_form()
 {
    var user = $('#Username').val(); // Username is the id of your input
    var password = $('#password').val(); // password is the id of your input
    $.ajax(
   {
     type:"POST", // or get as you want
     url:"myfile.php", // it is the php file which can do the job
     data: "user="+user+"&password="+password, // the param to send to your file, 
     success:function(msg)
     {
          ;// msg is the result of your 'myfile.php', everything you write is in the msg var

     }
  });
}
```

in your php file you can get your data like this :

```
 $user = $_POST['user'];
 $password = $_POST['password'];
 // if your type is get then use $_GET instead of $_POST
```

tell me if you have any problem with my code.

Comment: i forgot to say, in your function check_form() you must have a return false; at the end. If you don't when you'll validate your form the page will reload.

Comment: }); after this part i put the return false?

Comment: if I put echo to the php file, what should I put in the success:function(msg) { ?

Comment: yes put the return false here. In the php file you can echo "wrong login" or "wrong password" and in the success function you can test with if (msg == "wrong login" || msg == "wrong password") { alert(msg);}

Comment: How can I put the msg if I want to put it in the label? outside the script?

Comment: put an id at your label <label id='username'></label>. in your success function you can do $('#username').html('my message'); This function will replace the content of your label by the message in the html() function

Comment: where should I put the "msg" value?

Comment: the msg is a variable you can put it with the html() function $('#label').html(msg); will put the content of msg into the label id, you can put it in what you want.

Comment: thank you so much now i know :), can i still use this in input event onblur?

Comment: yes of course you can, just add onblur="your_function()" and it's ok.

Answer (score 0):

Write your validation script as though you're expecting a page refresh. Instead of outputting error messages, put them in a JSON array and print the JSON data. Then call the script from the AJAX function. It's really that simple.

```
<?php
// validate.php

$sampleInput_number = isset($_POST['sampleInput_number']) ? $_POST['sampleInput_number'] : "";

$errors = array();
if (trim($sampleInput_number) == "" || !is_numeric(trim($sampleInput_number)) {
    $errors[] = "SampleInput_number must be a number!";
}

// sample input must also match a value from the database
if (!matchesDBValue($sampleInput_number)) {
    $errors[] = "SampleInput_number must match a value from the database!";
}

function matchesDBValue($value) {
    $retval = false;

    // compare to db values here...

    return $retval;
}

echo json_encode($errors);
```

Your form would look something like this:

```
<form action="" method="post" id="theForm">
    <input type="text" name="sampleInput_number" id="sampleInput_number" />
    <input type="button" id="formSubmit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

And your javascript would look like this:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(#formSubmit).on("click", function() {
        $.post("validate.php", 
            {
                sampleInput_number: $("#sampleInput_number").val()
            }, function(data) {
                // check returned json data
                // perform action based on results

                if (no_errors) {
                    $("#theForm").submit();
                }
            }, "json"
        );
    });
</script>
```